# Triggering an event whenever a new window is focused?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I am writing an application using C# and WPF. Is there some way that my app can be notified whenever GetActiveWindow changes, or am I stuck with making a thread and monitoring the changes myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [Activated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.activated.aspx) event like:

```
//at window load or at the constructor
this.Activated += OnWindowActivated;

private void OnWindowActivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //your code here
}
```

**Edit:** As you want it to be for any window in the OS. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3886723/323339) similar question.

Comment: I need to know if the user changed focus on any window. Not just my window.

Comment: @dave on any window of your application or any window in OS?

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is the Win32 API

Comment: @Dave: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886723/can-i-use-window-hooks-in-c-to-determine-if-a-window-gains-or-loses-focus) similar question.