# wmi event active window/focus window

Tags: wmi, wmi-query, wql

Trying to trawl through the WMI/WQL MS Reference Data and the WMI Code Creator Event Classes, but can't find anything to indicate:

A) If this is possible
B) How to do it

Ideally i'd like to be able to subscribe to WMI Events that are of the nature of the End User changing (UI) window (any Windows application).

Comment: Why WMI in particular ?  
Take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44241/how-can-i-monitor-which-window-currently-has-keyboard-focus  
Windows API could be a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong tool, there is not WMI classes or WMI events related to the UI of a windows application. instead you must use the Windows messages and the WinAPI.