# How to monitor the active window on a remote PC

Tags: python, python-3.x, wmi, win32gui, active-window

I'm able to view the processes taking place on a remote computer on my network by using the `wmi` module.  This is an example using wmi to monitor the processes created and deleted on my own PC.

```
import wmi, multiprocessing

def create():
    while True:
        crePro = cp()
        print('Creation',crePro.Caption,crePro.ProcessId,crePro.CreationDate)


def delete():
    while True:
        delPro = dp()
        print('Deletion',delPro.Caption,delPro.ProcessId,delPro.CreationDate)


c = wmi.WMI()
cp = c.Win32_Process.watch_for("creation")
dp = c.Win32_Process.watch_for("deletion")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    createProc = multiprocessing.Process(target = create)
    deleteProc = multiprocessing.Process(target = delete)

    createProc.start()
    deleteProc.start()
```

I've also read about using `win32gui` to get the active window.

```
import win32gui
win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
```

And I've read about the existence of `WM_SETFOCUS` and `WM_ACTIVE` in `win32con`, but I'm not certain how to connect to these streams on a remote PC.

My question is:
How do I monitor the active window of a remote PC (I suppose using either `WM_SETFOCUS` or `WM_ACTIVE`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [wmi event active window/focus window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472216/wmi-event-active-window-focus-window)

Answer (score 1):

to get the Active window you can do this:

```
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow
active_window = GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow())
```

but, this isn't going to send a signal to you every time the active_window changes. You can read this from time to time and see if the active_window has changed.